# Getting list of Zoo Visitor entries with No Playa Parents and Solspace Super Search Result

Tags: solspace, playa, zoo-visitor, supersearch, zoo

I'm trying to get a Super Search results loop that only displays entries with No Parents...

I'm currently pulling out all the results and just showing a label for the entries that don't have a Playa parent:

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="zoo_visitor" status="Members-id5|Members_Verified_-id6|Members_Pro-id7|open" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="50" paginate="bottom" }

{if channel_name == 'zoo_visitor'}

    {exp:zoo_visitor:details} 

    <li>

      <strong>{mbr_formal_title} {member_firstname} {member_lastname} ({entry_id})</strong> 

      {exp:zoo_visitor:details}
      {exp:playa:parents channel="parents"} 

        {if total_results > 0}
            {title}
        {/if}

        {if no_parents}
            <span class="tip">No Parent</span>
        {/if}

      {/exp:playa:parents}
      {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}

    <hr>
    </li>

    {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}

{/if}  

<!-- Pagination Snippet -->
{_pagination}

{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Also happy to use default EE entries tag if it's easier / Super Search is causing the problem. Guessing it shouldn't make a difference though?

**Edit (Response to question):**

I tried this but it seems to spit out blank entries with parents...

```
{exp:super_search:results channel="zoo_visitor" status="open" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="50" paginate="bottom" }

  {exp:zoo_visitor:details}
  {exp:playa:parents channel="parents"} 
     {if no_parents}
      <li> {mbr_formal_title} {member_firstname} {member_lastname ({entry_id})</li>
    {/if}
  {/exp:playa:parents}
  {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}

{_pagination}

{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You don't like the loop depth? Slow queries? Just expand the namespace of your inner most loop and put everything inside that `no_parents` conditional.

Comment: When I put everything inside the no parents conditional, it still spits out blank list items for entries with parents. I just want to display ones without and nothing else. Hopefully that made sense?! 

Added an example above.

Comment: So something with no parents gets this: `<li> Output you wanted </li>` but stuff with parents gets this `<li> <!-- blank list item --> </li>` ?

Comment: Exactly. It's almost feels like the `{if no_parents}` tag needs to come with the entry tag.

Comment: tried adding an empty else clause? `{if no_parents} stuff goes here {if:else}{/if}`

Comment: OK. So couple things to report. Putting an empty else clause in just crashes and loads a blank page. Not sure how I was getting blank lines before, but at the moment using the edited code above, I just get empty tags e.g. `{mbr_formal_title} {member_firstname} {member_lastname} ({entry_id})`. These get printed out in the frontend.

Comment: Can't comment on the Zoo Visitor part, but shouldn't you be passing an entry_id in `{exp:playa:parents}`? Also, since Super Searches shares the same library with EE's Channel Entries, you could also try using `{exp:channel:entries}` to see if there's anything different (they should behave relatively the same).

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `exp:channel:entries` and `entry_id="{entry_id}"` but sadly the same problem occurs. I just get a list of printed out zoo visitor tags. Strangely it's actually paginated (but nothing appears on second page).  Tried just using the `{username}` tag too to negate it being anything to do with Zoo Visitor. That displays some usernames but with the `{no_parent}` tag they're just all the same username, which for the first member - (`entry_id="1"`).